# How to set the PreferredBackupWindow parameter in RDS CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, rds

I want to launch an RDS instance from CloudFormation.

I am constructing the JSON template based on the AWS documentation .

I want to set the *PreferredBackupWindow* parameter, but there is no example how to enter it's value.

I want to set it to create a snapshot every day at 6 in the morning.

How should I write it?? [`"PreferredBackupWindow" : String,`]

Something like `"PreferredBackupWindow" : "6:00UTC",` ??

Answer (score 5):

The preferred backup and maintenance can be set as the following string inputs:

```
MySQLDatabase:
  Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
  Properties:
    ...
    PreferredBackupWindow: "22:30-23:30"
    PreferredMaintenanceWindow: "mon:23:30-tue:00:30"
    ...
```

Please note that the time is set according to the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter string in following format hh24:mi-hh24:mi (24H Clock UTC).

For Example:

```
"PreferredBackupWindow": "19:30-20:00"
```